# how to avoid duplicate values to print in the html table

Tags: php, mysql

Order.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('conn.php');
    session_start();
    $itemId=$_SESSION['itemId'];
    $tnumber=$_SESSION['tnumber'];
    $custno=$_SESSION['custno'];

    $sql="select itemId,subtitle,price,quantity from cart where tnumber='$tnumber'" ;
    $sql2="select subtitle from cart where itemId='$itemId'";
    $res2=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql2);
    $row1=  mysqli_num_rows($res2);
    $res=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
    $total=0;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='cartbox.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
        <div id="shopping-cart"> </div>
        <?php
            echo "<table id='t1' border='1'>
                <th>Subtitle</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>";   
            if (row1 > 0) {
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $amount=$row['price']*$row['quantity'];
                    echo "<form id='addform{$row['itemId']}' method='post'   action='cartdelete.php'> ";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['subtitle'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['quantity'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['price'] ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $amount . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='submit' value='x' name='submit'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='itemId'  value= '{$row['itemId']}'></td>";   
                    echo"</form>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    $total = $total+ $amount;
                 }
             }
             echo "</table>";     
         ?>
         <?php echo $total ?> 
         <input type="button" name="continue" value="Continue Order" style="position: absolute;top:200px;" onclick="location.href='customerdicecream.php'">
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to display the data in an HTML table (with primary key). I need the subtitle to be entered into the HTML table, only once, but with the `if` condition I'm not able to achieve it. How can I do that?

Comment: use `group by subtitle`... in your query...

Comment: Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated, you shouldn't be using them.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: can u please give the query

Comment: Missing $ sign in the if condition `$row1 > 0` instead of `row1 > 0`

Comment: sorry its a typographical error @Pred

Comment: when i put the if before while,the while itself doesnt work..

Comment: please help.. how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `DISTINCT` / `GROUP BY` in your query for prevention of the redundant value.

ex.

```
$sql="select itemId,subtitle,price,quantity from cart where tnumber='$tnumber'" ;
    $sql2="select DISTINCT subtitle from cart where itemId='$itemId'";
```

[Reference Site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable `$prevSubTitle` before the `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {` condition.

And when you read value for it from `$row['subtitle']`, check if it matches with previously read value. If `'false'` display new value, else fill `td` with a space as `<td> &nbsp; </td>`

```
@prevSubTitle = '';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $amount=$row['price']*$row['quantity'];
    echo "<form id='addform{$row['itemId']}' method='post'   action='cartdelete.php'> ";
    echo "<tr>";

    $subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
    if( ! ( $subtitle == $prevSubTitle ) ) {
       $prevSubTitle = $subtitle;
    }
    else {
       $subtitle = ' &nbsp; ';
    }
    echo "<td>" . $subtitle ."</td>"; // empty when matched with previous row title

    echo "<td>" .$row['quantity'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['price'] ."</td>";
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply,this code does work,even now im able to insert 2 same subtitle into the html table